# How to configure camunda-platform (self managed) to use an external Keycloak 20.0.3 instance?

Tags: keycloak, camunda

I'm attempting to configure Camunda Platform 8 self managed. I would like to use an existing keycloak instance. However the `Identity` service cannot authenticate with Keycloak. Keycloak event logs show a invalid_user_credentials. If anyone has successfully connected camunda-platform with an external instance of Keycloak >20.0.3, what did you have to do?

My helm config for `camunda-platform` is as follows.

```yaml
kind-values.yaml
global:
  identity:
    keycloak:
      url:
        protocol: "http"
        host: "auth.local.growd.io"
        port: "80"
      contextPath: "/"
      auth:
        adminUser: "identity-admin"
        existingSecret: "keycloak-secret"
        existingSecretKey: "password"
    auth:
      enabled: false
      publicIssuerUrl: "https://auth.local.growd.io/realms/camunda-platform"
      operate:
        redirectUrl: "https://operate.camunda.local.growd.io"
      tasklist:
        redirectUrl: "https://taasklist.camunda.local.growd.io"
      optimize:
        redirectUrl: "https://optimize.camunda.local.growd.io"
     
identity:
  env:
    - name: KEYCLOAK_SETUP_CLIENT_ID
      value: identity_admin_cli
    - name: IDENTITY_LOG_LEVEL
      value: DEBUG
  keycloak:
    legacy: false
    enabled: false
    httpRelativePath: /

optimize:
  enabled: false

zeebe:
  clusterSize: 1
  partitionCount: 1
  replicationFactor: 1
  pvcSize: 10Gi

zeebe-gateway:
  replicas: 1

elasticsearch:
  imageTag: 7.17.3
  replicas: 1
  minimumMasterNodes: 1
  clusterHealthCheckParams: "wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=1s"
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "100m"
      memory: "512M"
    limits:
      cpu: "1000m"
      memory: "512M"

  volumeClaimTemplate:
    accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
    storageClass: "microk8s-hostpath"
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 15Gi
```

I can confirm the password in the secret is correct. Shelling into the identity container I see the `KEYCLOAK_SETUP_PASSWORD` is what I expect it to be.

ON start up, Identity attempts to authenticate with Keycloak. I see the following in the keycloak log;

```
2023-02-28 00:15:21,812 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-81) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=5d304d58-2aa5-4aa1-aecd-d643db489a76, clientId=identity_admin_cli, userId=9e29d31a-9047-40fc-9e72-61fa1c7ce4eb, ipAddress=127.0.0.6, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, grant_type=password, client_auth_method=client-secret, username=identity-admin, authSessionParentId=f86ce961-02e1-44cf-b918-60bc337e7294, authSessionTabId=95kqFzX1Zb0
```

Versions of stuff

camunda-platform: camunda-platform-8.1.6
keycloak: keycloak:20.0.3

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.camunda.io/docs/reference/supported-environments/#camunda-platform-8-self-managed states that identity supports only Keycloak 16.1.x, 18.x, 19.x versions.
I use helm chart 8.2.6 and keycloak 20.0.3 if I'm not mistaken.
If you try 8.3.0-alpha2 image tag of identity it will work:

```
identity:
    image:
      tag: 8.3.0-alpha2
    fullURL: https://my-camunda-identity-ns.example.com
    service:
      port: 8080
    env:
      - name: IDENTITY_CLIENT_SECRET
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: my-camunda-components-secret
            key: identity-secret
```